# What does the "s" mean in s-cis and s-trans conformations

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond

I am learning about conjugated unsaturated systems, and came upon s-cis and s-trans conformations in conjugated dienes.

So what does the "s" mean in s-cis and s-trans conformations?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The s stands for single, as in single bond. It means the double bonds are cis or trans to each other based around the single bond.
[image]

It is a common enough expression to search for, if more information is required.